# rails passing parameter from view to a different controller as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Im trying to pass a parameter (a file path : eg. `user/lauren/tools/`) from a view in RAILS to another different controller using RUBY. I want to use the file path (as a string) to be matched with a regular expression. To do that, right now Im using the `params [:parameter]` method as follows in the controller action where Im setting the variable instance:

```
@variable = /^.+\/[^\/]+$/.match(params[:name]).to_s ---where :name is the parameter passed from view
```

Right now, I dont get any output when I try to display that in the corresponding view of that controller....im guessing its the `params [:name]` method I need to replace or modify?

Id really appreciate views on this...thanks!

Comment: What's the `params[:name]` value when it hits your controller?

Answer (score 0):

While your server is running open a new terminal window and type rails console. This will let you see what your variables actually contain. You can type params and see what the hash has in it and see why your regex is failing. It sounds to me like you are trying to match your path, not your params.